# How does website know it's headless Puppeteer?

Tags: web-crawler, puppeteer

When I visit the target website, let's call it foo.com, but I've seen this on [youtube](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4696) and several other popular sites. In non-headless browser mode, everything works fine. But in headless mode, I get "sorry but your javascript is disabled, please try again". NO IT'S NOT DISABLED. How are they counteracting puppeteer? I tried changing the UserAgent string but to no avail. What else could be happening? I am also storing the complete state of the cookies/session/etc. with Puppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
```

Comment: install puppeteer,puppeteer-extra,puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth , itest it and dont have any problem in youtube  and facebook login